# Is there a word or phrase that’s the opposite of “drinking the kool-aid”?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests

Is there a word or phrase that’s the opposite of “drinking the kool-aid”? That phrase means you’ve been “on the inside” for so long that you can only see the good things.  I’m looking for a phrase that means you’ve been on the inside for so long that you can only see the bad things.

Comment: In the movie [_They Live_](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096256/) (1988), the opposite expression would be "wearing the sunglasses." Movie synopsis: "A drifter discovers a pair of sunglasses that allow him to wake up to the fact that aliens have taken over the Earth."

Comment: "Drinking the Kool-aid" means something very, very different, and usually has very negative connotations, as in self-destruction on command.

Comment: You need to study the source (the [Jonestown massacre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonestown)) of the term "drinking the Kool-Aid".  It means literally committing suicide because you believe blindly in your leader.

Comment: "Frog in boiling water"? It means you're so familiar with your surroundings that you may be oblivious to imminent danger, or in the context of your question, the transgressions of the group you're entangled with.

Answer (score 4):

"Drinking the Kool-Aid" does not mean being on the inside so long you see only good things. It means demonstrating unquestioning obedience or loyalty to someone or something--it could mean seeing only the good things, but that's imprecise. The phrase derives from James Jones' followers at Jonestown, who committed suicide by drinking poisonous Kool-Aid at his command. The opposite of this might be *skepticism*:

> any questioning attitude towards unempirical knowledge or
>   opinions/beliefs stated as facts, or doubt regarding claims that are
>   taken for granted elsewhere. (wikipedia)

Perhaps also, *distrust, mistrust, doubt, opposition, disbelief, to reject an idea, to renounce an idea, to disown an idea*

If you really want an insider's perspective that suggests an open-eyed view of the bad things one will encounter there, you might say that person is "*in the belly of the beast*."

Sometimes people refer to "*seeing how the sausage is made*," meaning that they are in a position to see the horrible things that go on in a particular place (such as a sausage factory that combines meat by-products that people would never eat in any other form).

Comment: Incredibly well put

Answer (score 2):

It's not a parallel construction to "drinking the kool-aid," but the opposite process is **becoming jaded**.

> **jaded**:  feeling or showing a lack of interest and excitement caused by having done or experienced too much of something
>   http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jaded